# What does "No compatible attachment provider is available" mean

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Recently I developed a java agent using [byte buddy](http://bytebuddy.net). The development in eclipse was fine, then I put the agent to production and the message:

`No compatible attachment provider is available`

along with some stacktraces originating from the lines

```
static {
  ByteBuddyAgent.install();
}
```

Comment: Actual error was "No compatible attachment provider is available" (the title of this question appears to have a typo)

Comment: I adjusted title and content to the correct wording.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some debugging I found the problem. The message "No compatible attachment provider is not available" occurs if the agent was called with a **jre** instead of a **jdk**.

Unfortunately calling `java -version` does not return whether `java` is a jdk or a jre (the message is displaying `Java runtime Environment` for both).

In my case (OS:Windows) it was tricky, because newer jsdk-installations attach `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` to the system path, which contains a jre and not a jdk. The formerly added entry `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` got hidden through this modification. When I removed the entry `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem starting a Spring Boot 2.3 application with a minimal JRE that was created with `jlink`. It would not start, and would keep throwing the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compatible attachment provider is available
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:602)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:586)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:538)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:515)
    at reactor.tools.agent.ReactorDebugAgent.init(ReactorDebugAgent.java:56)
```

I found out that this `ByteBuddyAgent` (from [this link](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-agent/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.java#L493)) requires the java module `jdk.attach` to be included, which was not the case in my minimal JRE.

After adding the `jdk.attach` module to my `jlink` command under `--add-modules`, the error went away and I could start my Spring Boot application again.