# Failed to init Reactor's debug agent

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea, project-reactor

I'm getting an error with intellij when running a spring boot application. Using mvn spring-boot:run works fine, however running with the intellij run/debug mode both return this exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to init Reactor's debug agent
    at org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
```

Removing this dependency causes it to run properly in intellij

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-tools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

[image: reactor debug settings]

Comment: What Spring Boot version do you use? Are there any any reactor specific notifications?

Comment: could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767683/what-does-no-compatible-attachment-provider-is-available-mean what did you use jre or jdk?