# "No compatible attachment provider is available" in Spring Docker container

Tags: java, spring, maven, containers

I'm trying to upgrade a spring boot project from version 2.6.7 to 3.1.1

The main functions uses `ReactorDebugAgent` from `reactor-tools`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReactorDebugAgent.init();
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

This was not changed during the upgrade. The projects runs locally fine but after building a container image via `mvn clean package spring-boot:build-image -B`, the container does not start with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compatible attachment provider is available
        at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:632)
        at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:616)
        at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:568)
        at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:545)
        at reactor.tools.agent.ReactorDebugAgent.init(ReactorDebugAgent.java:56)
        at com.maersk.publictracking.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:14)
        ... 8 more
```

[Similar questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767683/what-does-no-compatible-attachment-provider-is-available-mean) teach me that the issue is based on the JRE which does not include a modul that is needed by `bytebuddy` or `ReactiveDebugAgent`. This could explain why the issue only appears in the container and not locally but since the container image is created via MVN, I don't see any option for me to control the java modules inside the container.

Used java version: 17

Used pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.81</version>
    <name>my-application</name>
    <description>my-application</description>
    <properties>
        <io-grpc-netty.version>1.55.1</io-grpc-netty.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.10</jacoco.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <shared-error-handling-lib.version>3.1.0</shared-error-handling-lib.version>
        <spring-cloud-sleuth-otel.dependencies.version>1.1.3</spring-cloud-sleuth-otel.dependencies.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.6</spring-cloud.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.18.1</testcontainers.version>
        <tests.skip>false</tests.skip>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${io-grpc-netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>error-handling</artifactId>
            <version>${shared-error-handling-lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-tools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-sleuth-otel.dependencies.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rulesUri>file:///${basedir}//versions-rules.xml</rulesUri>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/foo/myapplication/models/**/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${tests.skip}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/acme-global/*</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This: `reactor.tools.shaded.net.` looks like you are using a dependency reactor-tools which shaded a dependency (bytebuddy which is in general a very bad idea) which results in such problem, because you can not overwrite the dependency for bytebuddy which is required to have a more recent version which works with JDK17...(the shaded version is an older one which does not support JDK17). You have to check if for reactor-tools a newer version is available compared the one you are using.... Furthermore it would be helpful to have a full pom file here etc...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added to pom.xml